# Excel 2013 VBA : when .xlsm file is open- impossible to open any other .xlsx file

Tags: excel, client-server, vba

I'm developping a .XLSM file as a Client to a .XLSX file as a "Server".

Whereas the Client is open, I cannot launch another instance of Excel 2013 by double-clicking on any .XLSX file.

It seems to put the focus back on my Client .XLSM file.

Do you have any tips to solve this ? 
I'd like to avoid to install an alternative Spreadsheet program.

Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: Does your XLSM workbook contain any application event procedures? Bear in mind that the problem seems to be the active window. You haven't said that the XLSX files don't open, just that they don't appear in the active window. However, I wonder if the XLSX files you wish to open are intended to be "Server" workbooks, as you describe. If they are supposed to be open in another instance of Excel all might be working as designed and all you need to do is to control the active window.

Comment: Thank you Variatus : your answer is very clear.
To be more complete, the need to open XLSX file is a parallel action to the application. Yes to the fact that there are a lot of event procedures.
The application generates billing workbooks and the end user grumbles because he cannot open the file generated while the application is still opened.

Comment: He wants also to use the Server file in parallel. The application is aimed to prevent this bad habit.

This "problem" set apart, the application works fine.
Once again, Thanks for your response.
Best regards

Comment: You aren't exactly clear on whether you wish to allow the opening of other workbooks or not, but going by your original question a solution should be possible based on the idea that the application events can be taught to handle some files different from others. I would start with finding out whether the invisible workbooks are actually opened or prevented from opening. If they are opened you might tweak the control over making them visible. Be careful though, because making them visible might invoke some other actions which would also have to be disabled.

Comment: In fact, opening other workbooks that do not contain macros is intended to check their datas because they were generated by the application.
Indeed, I dont know if when double-clicked the other files are opened and invisible or just not opened at all

Comment: `? Excel.Application.Workbooks.Count`, in the Immediate Window, will return the number of open workbooks, even if they are invisible. `? Excel.Application.Workbooks(1).Name` will do the same for the workbook's name.

Comment: I use the command for counting. Beforehand, I put a debug stop...
When waiting on this debug pause, I can open other XLSX file. On "idle" position, I cannot open..Cannot understand what happens...